# how to get the html of a span tag in a dynamically created input tag

Tags: html, jquery

```
<span class="edt">ddddd</span>
    <span class="edt">ssss</span>
    <span class="edt">aaaaa</span>
    <a id="edit">edit</a>


    $('#edit').click(function(){

       $('.edt').html("<input type=\"text\" id=\"\"  value=\"\" /> ") 
    });
```

what i want to do is get the html part of span tag in input created  by jquery. i knw the better solution will be to pass the html by id in variable but the span tags are dynamically created on page load.

Comment: So you want an input for each `edt` class with a value in the equal to what is in the `edt` node currently?

Comment: Are you trying to assign event handlers to dynamically created elements? In this case, span tags? What issue are you having with the code above?

Comment: try this : http://jsfiddle.net/FPt5s/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would loop through each `edt` class and replace the content of the span with and input element with same value as the content it is replacing.

```
$('#edit').click(function(){
    $('.edt').each(function() {
        var value = $(this).text();
        $(this).html('<input type="text" id="" value="'+value+'" />');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `#edit` element is created dynamically you should delegate the event.

```
$(document).on('click', '#edit', function(){
   $('span').html(function(index, oldHTML){
       return '<input type="text" id="id'+ index +'"  value="'+ oldHTML +'" />';
   })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yHbsa/

It seems you want to edit the element's content, some suggestions:

1. `Focus` on the input (programatically) and on `blur` event replace the inputs with their values.
2. If handler should be executed once, use `one` method instead of `on`.
3. If you are using HTML5 doctype you can also use `contenteditable` attribute instead of replacing elements.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve? **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/letiagoalves/337ER/5/)**

**Click on some input elements generated to see binded event.**

```
$('#content').on("click", "#edit", function () {
    $.each($('.edt'), function (i, k) {
        $(k).removeClass("edt");
        k.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='' value='" + k.innerHTML + "' />";
    });
});

$('#content').on("click", "input", function () {
    alert("Some event.");
});
```